# Change value tag PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to change the value of the tag for the value of a variable with php;

```
$tag = '<string name="abs__action_bar_home_description">My old title</string>';
$new_title = 'My new title';
```

result:

```
<string name="abs__action_bar_home_description">**My new title**</string>
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate HTML code? If yes, use DOMDocument with DOMXPath, this combination is really powerful and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php the function preg_replace. Example for you [here](http://ideone.com/dczSPv)

```
<?php

$tag = '<string name="abs__action_bar_home_description">My old title</string>';
$new_title = 'My new title';

$pattern = "/(<string[\s\w=\"]*>)([\w\s]*)(<\/string>)/i";
$replacement = "$1".$new_title."$3";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement ,$tag);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Hi, does not work when you have "?". Example. $ tag = '<string name = "key"> Confirm your note in the Play Store? </ string>'

Comment: You should change 6th line of code: `$pattern = "/(<string[\s\w=\"]*>)(.*)(<\/ string>)/i";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve the same with no regex, but with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$tag = '<string name="abs__action_bar_home_description">My old title</string>';
$new_title = 'My new title';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$dom->loadHTML($tag, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//string[@name="abs__action_bar_home_description"]');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->nodeValue = $new_title;
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/yFQ2Dv)

The `'//string[@name="abs__action_bar_home_description"]'` xpath means that you want to get `string` tag that has an attribute `name` with the value of `abs__action_bar_home_description`.

If you load an HTML file, you can use something like

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com/content.html");
```